# Function is alerting incorrect value/text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am testing out a form i am trying to build and i am trying to return different values each time i click a different list item from my dropdown menu, i hope that makes sense, maybe take a quick peek at my pen and perhaps it will be explained clearer https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/GmrgVL?editors=1010

```
var val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text()
var val2 = $("#box2 p:first-child").text()

$("#box1").click(function(){
    $("#dropdown2").removeClass('appear')
    $("#dropdown1").toggleClass('appear')  
})

$("#dropdown1 ul li a").click(function(){
    $("#box1 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#box1 p:first-child").val($(this).text());
    alert(val1)
})
```

each time i click either Placeholder 1, 2 or 3 they all return just "Placeholder" for some reason, i need them to return their complete text, for example if i click on "Placeholder 1" it should return "Placeholder 1" and not just "Placeholder"

any help is appreciated as i am completely stumped

Comment: Your code is fetching the content of the `<p>` tag, and that tag **ends** before the content you're expecting to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining `val1` as `$("#box1 p:first-child").text()` when the page loads, then changing the contents of `#box1 p:first-child` - so you need to re-define that variable if you want to alert with the new contents of `$("#box1 p:first-child").text()`.

I moved `val1` into your click handler, after you change it's contents with `$.text()` since that's the only place you reference that variable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var val2 = $("#box2 p:first-child").text();

  $("#box1").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown2").removeClass("appear");
    $("#dropdown1").toggleClass("appear");
  });

  $("#dropdown1 ul li a").click(function() {
    $("#box1 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#box1 p:first-child").val($(this).text());

    var val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text();

    alert(val1);

    // switch (val1) {
    //   case "Placeholder 1":
    //     alert("test");
    //   case "Placeholder 2":
    //   alert("test2");
    //     break;
    //   default:
    //     alert("test3");
    //   }
  });

  $("#box2").click(function() {
    $("#dropdown1").removeClass("appear");
    $("#dropdown2").toggleClass("appear");
  });

  $("#dropdown2 ul li a").click(function() {
    $("#box2 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#box2 p:first-child").val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* containers */

#wrapper {

  height: 560px;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#container {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/* rows */

#row1, #row2, #row3 {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

#row2 {
  top: 240px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#row3 {
  top: 400px;
}



/* box containers */

.box-wrapper {
  background: blue;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}




/* boxes */

#box1, #box2 {
  background: #333;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#box2 {
  right: 0;
}

#box3, #box4, #box5 {
  background: #333;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#box4 {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#box5 {
  right: 0;
}

#box6, #box7 {
  background: #333;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#box7 {
  right: 0;
}



/* box text */

#box1 p, #box2 p, #box3 p, #box4 p, #box5 p, #box6 p, #box7 p {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}



/* dropdown */

#dropdown1, #dropdown2 {
  background: #000;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

#dropdown1 ul, #dropdown2 ul {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#dropdown1 ul li, #dropdown2 ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

#dropdown1 ul li a, #dropdown2 ul li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}






/* show dropdown */

.appear {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    
    <div id="row1">
      <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div id="box1">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
          <div id="dropdown1" class="dropdown">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="box2">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
          <div id="dropdown2" class="dropdown">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Placeholder 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="row2">
      <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div id="box3">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box4">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="box5">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="row3">
      <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div id="box6">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
        </div>

        <div id="box7">
          <p>Placeholder</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a gem! I'd kiss you if I could. Anyway, I'll mark your answer as the correct answer once it lets me in 6 minutes.

Comment: @AlexYap awesome :-*

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset val1 after the text value has changed.  You might also want to consistently end you lines with ;

```
$("#dropdown1 ul li a").click(function(){
    $("#box1 p:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $("#box1 p:first-child").val($(this).text());

    val1 = $("#box1 p:first-child").text();

    alert(val1);
});
```